# Prove that $Q=\{(x_1,...,x_n)\in \mathbb R^n\mid \forall i, x_i\geq 0\}$ is a topological manifold with boundary.

Tags: manifolds

I have to prove that $Q=\{(x_1,...,x_n)\in \mathbb R^n\mid \forall i=1,...,n,\  x_i\geq 0\}$ is a topological manifold with boundary. The fact that the topology is second countable and hausdorff is a consequence of the fact that it's a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and thus it inherit of those properties from $\mathbb R^n$.

**1)** Is it correct to say that ?

I have difficulties to show that it's locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb H^n=\{(x_1,...,x_n)\mid x_n\geq 0\}$, any idea ?

Comment: Do you mean a *topological* manifold with boundary?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: Try it for $n=2,3$ first, then generalise.

Comment: I of course did it, but it's not conclusif... May be there is an easier way @Arthur

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question: Yes, any subset of $\mathbb R^n$ (with the subspace topology) is Hausdorff and second countable, because those properties are [hereditary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditary_property#In_topology).

Suggestion: To show that $Q$ is a topological manifold with boundary, first prove that if $f\colon \mathbb R^{n-1}\to \mathbb R$ is any continuous function, then the set
$$\{(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb R^n: x_n\ge f(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}\}$$
is a topological manifold with boundary. Then try to find a linear isomorphism from $\mathbb R^n$ to itself that takes $Q$ to a set of this form.